# Can UNION ALL be faster than JOINs or do my JOINs just suck?

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2008

I have a `Notes` table with a `uniqueidentifier` column that I use as a FK for a variety of other tables in the database (don't worry, the `uniqueidentifier` columns on the other tables aren't clustered PKs).  These other tables represent something of a hierarchy of business objects.  As a simple representation, let's say I have two other tables:

- **Leads** (PK LeadID)
- **Quotes** (PK QuoteID, FK LeadID)

In the display of a `Lead` in the application, I need to show all notes related to the lead, including those tagged to any `Quote` that belongs to that lead.  I have two options as far as I can see — either a `UNION ALL` or several `LEFT JOIN` statements.  Here's how they'd look:

```
SELECT N.*  
FROM Notes N  
JOIN Leads L ON N.TargetUniqueID = L.UniqueID  
WHERE L.LeadID = @LeadID

UNION ALL

SELECT N.*  
FROM Notes N  
JOIN Quotes Q ON N.TargetUniqueID = Q.UniqueID  
WHERE Q.LeadID = @LeadID
```

Or...

```
SELECT N.*  
FROM Notes N  
LEFT JOIN Leads L ON N.TargetUniqueID = L.UniqueID  
LEFT JOIN Quotes Q ON N.TargetUniqueID = Q.UniqueID  
WHERE L.LeadID = @LeadID OR Q.LeadID = @LeadID
```

In real life I have a total of five tables that the notes could be attached to, and that number could grow as the application grows.  I already have non-clustered indexes set up on the `uniqueidentifier` columns I'm using, and SQL Profiler says I can't make any more improvements, but when I do a performance test on a realistically-sized test data set, I get the following numbers:

- `UNION ALL` — 0.010 sec
- `LEFT JOIN` — 0.744 sec

I had always heard that using `UNION` was bad, and that `UNION ALL` was only marginally better, but the performance numbers don't seem to bear that out.  Granted, the `UNION ALL` SQL code might be more of a pain to maintain, but at that kind of performance difference it's probably worth it.

So is `UNION ALL` really better here or am I missing something on the `LEFT JOIN` code that is slowing things down?

Comment: Did you run the UNION or the JOIN query first?  Bear in mind in SQL Server your querys can be cached which can give you a faster result on a second run.

Comment: In my tests I ran the UNION first.  In both cases I ran them several times without.  The first run of any query was definitely slower than subsequent runs, but the numbers leveled out at those times I listed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `UNION ALL` version would probably be satisfied quite easily by 2 index seeks. `OR` can lead to scans. What do the execution plans look like?

Also have you tried this to avoid accessing `Notes` twice?

```
;WITH J AS
(
SELECT UniqueID FROM Leads WHERE LeadID = @LeadID
UNION ALL
SELECT UniqueID FROM Quotes WHERE LeadID = @LeadID
)

SELECT N.*  /*Don't use * though!*/
FROM Notes N  
JOIN J ON N.TargetUniqueID = J.UniqueID
```

Comment: +1 - UNION ALL is nice and fast if you know your data integrity is good (i.e. no dupes in original datasets).

Comment: Checking the execution plans showed that the UNION ALL could benefit from one more index...and it's fast as it is.

The JOINS with the OR statements do indeed result in one expensive index scan, though I'm not sure which parts of that result would be relevant to provide here...any tips?

Comment: @Josh - Just out of interest what happens in the JOIN version if you replace `@LeadID` with a constant (e.g. `120` or whatever you are currently passing in) do you get the same plan with the scan?

Comment: Right...forgot about a CTE!  That pushed the query down to 0.007 sec, and makes it a lot less code that would be much easier to maintain.

And yes, same plan whether constant or `int` variable.

As for the *, I'm only using that in development -- all production queries have explicit column selects.

Answer (score 3):

I may be wrong, but I think that you will get a better performance if you rewrite you JOIN version to

```
SELECT N.*  
FROM Notes N  
LEFT JOIN Leads L ON N.TargetUniqueID = L.UniqueID AND L.LeadID = @LeadID  
LEFT JOIN Quotes Q ON N.TargetUniqueID = Q.UniqueID  AND Q.LeadID = @LeadID
WHERE Q.LeadID IS NOT NULL OR L.LeadID IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: Wow, you're right — it went down to 0.166 sec.  Still slower than the UNION ALL but definitely a massive improvement over the original JOINs.  I would not have expected that...why would this be better?

Comment: From what I remember about SQL server query processing, `JOIN` processed  before `WHERE`, so the more rows we eliminate in `JOIN` phase, the faster query would be. However, I'm a bit confused because here we have OUTER, not INNER join . Maybe `IS [NOT] NULL` works much faster than `=`, I cannot tell for sure... I tried similar queries in Mysql and it also showed the same results (this query is about 5-7 times faster than your original).

Answer (score 1):

In my experience, SQL Server is really bad with join conditions containing `OR`. I also use `UNION`s in that case, and I got similar results like you (maybe half a second instead of 20).

Who said UNIONS are bad? Especially if you use `UNION ALL`, there should not be a performance hit, as `UNION` would have to go through the result to only keep unique records (actually doing something like distinct or `group by`).

Answer (score 1):

You second query wouldn' even give correct results as it would covert the left joins to inner joins, see here for explantion as to why your syntax is bad:

http://wiki.lessthandot.com/index.php/WHERE_conditions_on_a_LEFT_JOIN

Comment: It does produce the correct results, though.  I suspect the difference is that I'm using ORs instead of ANDs in the WHERE clause.  In your link, the AND-ed conditions result in a limitation of the result set, hence the "conversion" to an inner join.  I don't think that's the same thing as this scenario, is it?

Answer (score 0):

UNION is slower, but UNION ALL should be pretty quick, right?