# WHERE in Sql, combining two fast conditions multiplies costs many times

Tags: sql, performance, t-sql, sql-server-2005

I have a fairly complex sql that returns 2158 rows' id from a table with ~14M rows. I'm using CTEs for simplification.

The `WHERE` consists of two conditions. If i comment out one of them, the other runs in ~2 second. If i leave them both (separated by `OR`) the query runs ~100 seconds. The first condition alone needs 1-2 seconds and returns 19 rows, the second condition alone needs 0 seconds and returns 2139 rows.

What can be the reason?

This is the complete SQL:

```
WITH fpcRepairs AS
(
    SELECT FPC_Row = ROW_NUMBER()OVER(PARTITION BY t.SSN_Number ORDER BY t.Received_Date, t.Claim_Creation_Date, t.Repair_Completion_Date, t.Claim_Submitted_Date)
    ,   idData, Repair_Completion_Date, Received_Date, Work_Order, SSN_number, fiMaxActionCode, idModel,ModelName
    ,   SP=(SELECT TOP 1 Reused_Indicator FROM tabDataDetail td INNER JOIN tabSparePart sp ON td.fiSparePart=sp.idSparePart
            WHERE td.fiData=t.idData
            AND (td.Material_Quantity <> 0) 
            AND (sp.SparePartName = '1254-3751'))
    FROM   tabData AS t INNER JOIN
       modModel AS m ON t.fiModel = m.idModel 
    WHERE (m.ModelName = 'LT26i') 
    AND EXISTS(
        SELECT  NULL 
        FROM    tabDataDetail AS td 
        INNER JOIN tabSparePart AS sp ON td.fiSparePart = sp.idSparePart
        WHERE  (td.fiData = t.idData) 
        AND (td.Material_Quantity <> 0) 
        AND (sp.SparePartName = '1254-3751')
    ) 
), needToChange AS
(
    SELECT idData FROM tabData AS t INNER JOIN
       modModel AS m ON t.fiModel = m.idModel
    WHERE (m.ModelName = 'LT26i') 
    AND EXISTS(
        SELECT  NULL 
        FROM    tabDataDetail AS td 
        INNER JOIN tabSparePart AS sp ON td.fiSparePart = sp.idSparePart
        WHERE  (td.fiData = t.idData) 
        AND (td.Material_Quantity <> 0) 
        AND (sp.SparePartName IN ('1257-2741','1257-2742','1248-2338','1254-7035','1248-2345','1254-7042'))
    ) 
)
SELECT t.idData
FROM tabData AS t INNER JOIN modModel AS m ON t.fiModel = m.idModel
INNER JOIN needToChange ON t.idData = needToChange.idData  -- needs to change FpcAssy
LEFT OUTER JOIN fpcRepairs rep ON t.idData = rep.idData
WHERE   
rep.idData IS NOT NULL          -- FpcAssy replaced, check if reused was claimed correctly
AND rep.FPC_Row > 1             -- other FpcAssy repair before
AND (
    SELECT SP FROM fpcRepairs lastRep
    WHERE lastRep.SSN_Number = rep.SSN_Number
    AND lastRep.FPC_Row = rep.FPC_Row - 1
) = rep.SP                      -- same SP, must be rejected(reused+reused or new+new)
OR      
rep.idData IS NOT NULL          -- FpcAssy replaced, check if reused was claimed correctly
AND rep.FPC_Row = 1             -- no other FpcAssy repair before
AND rep.SP = 0                  -- not reused, must be rejected
order by t.idData
```

Here's the execution plan:

Download: http://www.filedropper.com/exeplanfpc

Comment: Did you try to use UNION of 2 queries separately instead of OR condition?

Comment: @hgulyan: If you'd post it as answer i would at least upvote it. It needs only 3 seconds with a `UNION ALL`. Why?

Comment: ok, thanks. I just wasn't sure if it was your case. Try UNION too, instead of UNION ALL :)

Comment: @hgulyan: Why shall i use `UNION`? `UNION ALL` is faster and both conditions are mutually exclusive(FPC_Row = 1 and FPC_Row > 1).

Comment: Oh, sorry, you're right, my mistake.

Comment: I don't understand the use of left join. Unmatched rows are thrown away anyway by any `rep.xxx` condition.

Comment: @TimSchmelter - Re: Why? See http://stackoverflow.com/q/5901791/73226

Comment: @NikolaMarkovinović: Actually there's a third condition which starts with `rep.idData IS NULL`. I just didn't want to overcomplicate it unnecessarily.

Comment: @Martin Smith Very good explanation!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to use **UNION ALL** of 2 queries separately instead of **OR** condition.

I've tried it many times and it really helped. I've read about this issue in [Art Of SQL](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596008945) .

Read it, you can find many useful information about performance issues.

**UPDATE:**

Check related questions

[UNION ALL vs OR condition in sql server query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5639710/union-all-vs-or-condition-in-sql-server-query)

http://www.sql-server-performance.com/2011/union-or-sql-server-queries/

[Can UNION ALL be faster than JOINs or do my JOINs just suck?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3374459/can-union-all-be-faster-than-joins-or-do-my-joins-just-suck)

Check Wes's answer

> The usage of the OR is probably causing the query optimizer to no longer use an index in the second query.